# Sshutle connection refused while trying to connect to server

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

After i install new version of ubuntu (18.04), and installed sshittleI couldn't connect to my server anymore with sshuttle.
And also I checked the version (0.78.4) was also the same I used on another device and that was ok.
You can see error massage below:

```
$ ./sshuttle --dns -r leto@example.com 0/0 -vv
Starting sshuttle proxy.
Binding: 12300
Listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
DNS listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
[local sudo] Password: 
Sorry, try again.
[local sudo] Password: 
firewall manager ready.
c : connecting to server...
c : executing: ['ssh', 'leto@example.com', '--', 'P=python2; $P -V         2>/dev/null || P=python; "$P" -c \'import sys; skip_imports=1;     verbosity=2; exec compile(sys.stdin.read(764), "assembler.py", "exec")\'']
c :  > channel=0 cmd=PING len=7 (fullness=0)
server: assembling 'cmdline_options.py' (29 bytes)
server: assembling 'helpers.py' (693 bytes)
server: assembling 'ssubprocess.py' (13702 bytes)
server: assembling 'ssnet.py' (5100 bytes)
server: assembling 'hostwatch.py' (2242 bytes)
server: assembling 'server.py' (2380 bytes)
 s: latency control setting = True
 s: available routes:
 s:   173.255.217.0/24
 s:  > channel=0 cmd=PING len=7 (fullness=0)
 s:  > channel=0 cmd=ROUTES len=17 (fullness=7)
 s: Waiting: 1 r=[4] w=[5] x=[] (fullness=24/0)
 s:   Ready: 1 r=[] w=[5] x=[]
 s: mux wrote: 15/15
 s: mux wrote: 25/25
 s: Waiting: 1 r=[4] w=[] x=[] (fullness=24/0)
c : connected.
Connected.
c : Waiting: 3 r=[3, 5, 9] w=[9] x=[] (fullness=7/0)
c :   Ready: 3 r=[9] w=[9] x=[]
c : <  channel=0 cmd=PING len=7
c :  > channel=0 cmd=PONG len=7 (fullness=7)
c : <  channel=0 cmd=ROUTES len=17
firewall manager: starting transproxy.
>> iptables -t nat -N sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -F sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT 1 -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j RETURN --dest 127.0.0.0/8 -p     tcp
>> iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j REDIRECT --dest 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --to-ports 12300 -m ttl ! --ttl 42
>> iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j REDIRECT --dest XX.7.43.10/32 -p udp --dport 53 --to-ports 12300 -m ttl ! --ttl 42
>> iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j REDIRECT --dest XX.7.33.10/32 -p udp --dport 53 --to-ports 12300 -m ttl ! --ttl 42
c : mux wrote: 15/15
c : mux wrote: 15/15
c : Waiting: 3 r=[3, 5, 9] w=[] x=[] (fullness=14/0)
Write failed: Broken pipe
c :   Ready: 3 r=[9] w=[] x=[]
firewall manager: undoing changes.
>> iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -F sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -X sshuttle-12300
c : fatal: server died with error code 255
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some researches i found out how to use it but I didn't understand issue!
if you use `--exclude serverIp/serverDomain` in your sshuttle command it will has errors but doesn't refused.
If anyone know this issue, please mention it here.